# Mapping Stored Procedure Parameters to different Types

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ef-database-first

I'm trying to map some insert/update stored procedures to a table in EF. But one of my column types (string) in the stored procedure is different to the column in the table (geometry).

I have a `Geometry` column in the table that I want to populate in the stored procedure by passing it a string value.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdatePLACE] 
    @globalid uniqueidentifier,
    @shapeString varchar(max) = null    
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @shape as geometry  
    set @shape = geometry::STGeomFromText(@shapeString, 2193)

    UPDATE [dbo].[PLACE]
    SET [SHAPE] = @shape
    WHERE [globalid] = @globalid
END
```

So, is it possible to map a string to a geometry type and how?

Comment: what is the version of your EF ?? 
I think this link may help you : 

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/CRUD-using-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: I think it's v5. Will try it later. Thank you

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The proper solution would be to fix the stored procedure and pass a Geometry value from EF. Geometry types [are supported from EF 5 and up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859721.aspx)

Comment: OK I wondered if that was the only option... I'm using existing stored procedures, so I guess I'll have to modify them